Passing arguments to eclipse through flatpak
I run eclipse on linux mint. The installation uses flatpack as an envelope for execution. The exact command is: /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=eclipse --file-forwarding org.eclipse.Java I want to pass the workspace path to eclipse and after googling, found that eclipse can take an argument specifying the workspace. Specifically, it is the -data argument, which takes a path to the workspace. So, I tried: /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=eclipse -data <absolute path to workspace> --file-forwarding org.eclipse.Java However, flatpack returned an error stating it did not recognize -data. I then put the -data argument in both single quotes and double quotes, e.g., /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=eclipse "-data <absolute path to workspace>" --file-forwarding org.eclipse.Java Flatpack still returned the unrecognized error.
Can anyone advise me how to pass this argument to eclipse when it is executed through flatpack?

This seems to be flatpak not [tag:flatpack]. Questions about a Linux command belong on [unix.se] which has 150+ questions about flatpak

Eclipse also already provides packaged downloadable tarballs that can usually update themselves. You need only unpack it into a location where your user has full permissions. No need to wait on, or trust in, whomever created that flatpak.

The only sensible thing with the quotes would be /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command="eclipse -data <absolute path to workspace>".

@rzwitserloot: Quoting the whole command seemed to get around the unrecognized error, but now flatpak can't seem to find the eclipse executable. However, per the suggestion by greg-449, this is probable a flatpak question and I will move it to Unix & Linux.
